# Java8 dynamic proxy and default methods

Tags: java, java-8

Having a dynamic proxy for an interface with default methods, how do I invoke a default method? By using something like `defaultmethod.invoke(this, ...)` you just get your proxy invocation handler called (Which is somehow correct, cause you have no implementing class for this interface).

I have a workaround using ASM to create a class implementing the interface and delegating such calls to an instance of this class. But this is not a good solution, especially if the default method calls other interface methods (you get a delegator ping-pong). The JLS is surprisingly silent about this question...

Here a small code example:

```java
public class Java8Proxy implements InvocationHandler {
    public interface WithDefaultMethod {
        void someMethod();

        default void someDefaultMethod() {
            System.out.println("default method invoked!");
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void invokeTest() {
        WithDefaultMethod proxy = (WithDefaultMethod) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            WithDefaultMethod.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class<?>[] { WithDefaultMethod.class }, this);
        proxy.someDefaultMethod();

    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {

        // assuming not knowing the interface before runtime (I wouldn't use a
        // proxy, would I?)
        // what to do here to get the line printed out?

        // This is just a loop
        // method.invoke(this, args);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [MethodHandles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html) type in your *InvocationHandler*.  This code is copied from [Zero Turnaround](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/recognize-and-conquer-java-proxies-default-methods-and-method-handles/).

```
Constructor<MethodHandles.Lookup> constructor;
Class<?> declaringClass;
Object result;

if (method.isDefault()) {
   declaringClass = method.getDeclaringClass();
   constructor = MethodHandles.Lookup.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.class, int.class);

   constructor.setAccessible(true);

   result = constructor.
      newInstance(declaringClass, MethodHandles.Lookup.PRIVATE).
      unreflectSpecial(method, declaringClass).
      bindTo(proxy).
      invokeWithArguments(args);

   return(result);
}
```

Comment: This works. I needed one more hint, the proxy object must me known in the invocation handler. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Cfx [this is not supported in a native way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66751950/1059372)

Comment: @Eugene bad typo, I suppose, “not” should be “now”.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer uses `setAccessible(true)` to break into `MethodHandles.Lookup`, something that is restricted in Java 9 and beyond. This [mail](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2017-January/010741.html) describes a JDK change that works for Java 9 or later.

It is possible to get this to work on Java 8 (and later) if you can get the writer of the interface to call your utility with an instance of `MethodHandles.Lookup` created in the interface (so it gets the permission to access the default methods of the interface):

```
interface HelloGenerator {
  public static HelloGenerator  createProxy() {
    // create MethodHandles.Lookup here to get access to the default methods
    return Utils.createProxy(MethodHandles.lookup(), HelloGenerator.class);
  }
  abstract String name();
  default void sayHello() {
    System.out.println("Hello " + name());
  }
}

public class Utils {
  static <P> P createProxy(MethodHandles.Lookup lookup, Class<P> type) {
    InvocationHandler handler = (proxy, method, args) -> {
        if (method.isDefault()) {
          // can use unreflectSpecial here, but only because MethodHandles.Lookup
          // instance was created in the interface and passed through
          return lookup
              .unreflectSpecial(method, method.getDeclaringClass())
              .bindTo(proxy)
              .invokeWithArguments(args);
        }
        return ...; // your desired proxy behaviour
    };

    Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        type.getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[] {type}, handler);
    return type.cast(proxy);
  }
}
```

This approach won't handle all Java 8 use cases, but it did handle mine.

Comment: Perhaps you could add the solution from the email you linked to the answer. Anyone reading this today will probably want to use that solution (using `findSpecial`) instead of the Java 8 workaround.

Comment: @Jorn and finally this is supported in [a native way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66751950/1059372)

Answer (score 7):

Since [jdk-16](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html) this is supported in a native way, via `invokeDefault`.

To your example, this would be done as:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class InvocationHandlerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WithDefaultMethod proxy = (WithDefaultMethod) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                WithDefaultMethod.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class<?>[] { WithDefaultMethod.class }, new Java8Proxy());
        proxy.someDefaultMethod();
    }

     interface WithDefaultMethod {
        void someMethod();

        default void someDefaultMethod() {
            System.out.println("default method invoked!");
        }
    }

    static class Java8Proxy implements InvocationHandler {

        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("invoked");
            InvocationHandler.invokeDefault(proxy, method, args);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

---

But you do not need an explicit implementation of the interface that you need, this can be done slightly different:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class InvocationHandlerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WithDefaultMethod proxy = (WithDefaultMethod) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                WithDefaultMethod.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class<?>[] { WithDefaultMethod.class },
                (o, m, params) -> {
                    if (m.isDefault()) {
                        // if it's a default method, invoke it
                        return InvocationHandler.invokeDefault(o, m, params);
                    }
                    return null;
                });

        proxy.someDefaultMethod();

    }

     interface WithDefaultMethod {
        void someMethod();

        default void someDefaultMethod() {
            System.out.println("default method invoked!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up a blog entry detailing the different approaches that must be used for Java 8 and 9+: http://netomi.github.io/2020/04/17/default-methods.html

It includes code from the spring framework to handle the different cases in a clean and efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

This is annoyingly stupid counter-intuitive behaviour, which I assert is a bug in method#invoke(Object,Object[]), because you can't keep things simple in an InvocationHandler, like:

```
if (method.isDefault())
    method.invoke(proxy, args);
else
    method.invoke(target, args); // to call a wrapped object
```

So have to do a special lookup for a MethodHandle, and bind to proxy, to call, it.

I refined the McDowell provided code as follows (simplified):

```
private static final Constructor<MethodHandles.Lookup> lookupConstructor;

static {
    try {
        lookupConstructor = MethodHandles.Lookup.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.class, int.class);
        lookupConstructor.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static MethodHandle findDefaultMethodHandle(Class<?> facadeInterface, Method m) {
    try {
        Class<?> declaringClass = m.getDeclaringClass();
        // Used mode -1 = TRUST, because Modifier.PRIVATE failed for me in Java 8.
        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = lookupConstructor.newInstance(declaringClass, -1);
        try {
            return lookup.findSpecial(facadeInterface, m.getName(), MethodType.methodType(m.getReturnType(), m.getParameterTypes()), declaringClass);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            try {
                return lookup.unreflectSpecial(m, declaringClass);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException x) {
                x.addSuppressed(e);
                throw x;
            }
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw (RuntimeException) e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static class InvocationHandlerImpl implements InvocationHandler {
    private final Class<?> facadeInterface;

    private Object invokeDefault(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        MethodHandle mh = findDefaultMethodHandle(facadeInterface, m);
        return mh.bindTo(proxy).invokeWithArguments(args);
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if (method.isDefault()) {
            return invokeDefault(proxy, method, args);
        }
        // rest of code method calls
      }
 }
```

facadeInterface is the interface being proxied, which declares the default method, it will probably be possible to use super-interface default methods too.

Non-toy code should do this lookup before invoke is called, or at least cache the MethodHandle.