# How can I instantiate an interface at runtime?

Tags: java, interface, instantiation

I have an interface with default methods only.

```java
interface Some {
    default void doSome() {
    }
}
```

And I'm creating some sort of proxy instance from it.

```java
(Some) getProxy(new Class<?>[]{Some.class}, new Some() {});
```

Now I want some utility method of doing it for any interface.

Is there any nice way to do that?

```java
<T> T static proxy(final Class<T> clazz) {
    // @@? How can I do `new T(){}` from the class?
}
```

Comment: Seems like an unusual approach to solve _something_, could you provide information about why you try to achieve this?

Comment: what's the point of the proxy when you already get an instance of the interface with `new Some() {}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to call a default interface method from a dynamic proxy ([`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)) using [`java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html).

```
public interface Some {

  default void doSome() {
    System.out.println("something...");
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  static <T> T getProxy(Class<T> clazz) {
    return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        clazz.getClassLoader(),
        new Class[]{clazz},
        (proxy, method, args) -> MethodHandles.lookup()
            .in(clazz)
            .unreflectSpecial(method, clazz)
            .bindTo(proxy)
            .invokeWithArguments());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Some some = getProxy(Some.class);
    some.doSome();
  }
}
```

The `main` method prints:

```
something...
```

Comment: This is beautiful. I also referred https://stackoverflow.com/a/49532463/330457