# Instantiate an interface using java reflections?

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible to instantiate an interface just using java reflections?
I would like to have a factory method - producing interfaces, just by knowing its class.

```
public interface IReflection {

    public default String say(){
        return  "test default";
    }

}


public <T> T factoryProduce(Class<T> type){
    // how to instantiate on factoryProduce(IReflection.class)
}
```

I am trying to simulate the following using reflections.
Because for the following I can not dynamically get the interface class

```
return new IReflection(){}
```

Using `newInstance()` failed, cause there is no constructor in the interface.

```
Constructor<?>[] con = IReflection.class.getDeclaredConstructors(); // empty
i = IReflection.class.newInstance();    // no constructor
i = IReflection.class.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(); // no constructor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces don't have constructors. They don't take part in the chain of constructors, implicitly or explicitly, calling super from the most derived class to `java.lang.Object`.

I suggest avoiding reflection, but if you absolutely have to for some reason, there is `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`. Unfortunately it does proxy default methods. There is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49730826/4725) as a dirty hack around, or write a class loader to load a simple subtype.

Comment: Uh, I think I really will avoid reflections or Proxy classes here. Will prefer keep my code understandable instead

Answer (score 1):

An interface cannot be instantiated, not even with reflection (and not even when all its methods have a default implementation). You can only instantiate a class that implements the interface.

If you have a small set of interfaces that you need `factoryProduce` to support, you can simply create an implementing class for each of them, and create a map from interface type to implementing class. `factoryProduce` can then get the implementing class from this map, and instantiate it with reflection.

If you really need a completely dynamic solution, look at [dynamic proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html), which are capable of creating a class at runtime that implements a given set of interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot - of course - instantiate the interface, but you can instantiate the [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object defining the interface.

It is possible to compile the interface "on the fly" from a `String` containing the definition using `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` obtained from `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()` and then use the `java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass()` to define the class on the fly.

PS: I am using this technique in [Obba](http://obba.info), an Object Handler for Spreadsheets (there is an example that creates a class from a String containing the code during runtime).